# How to fix "couldn't follow symbolic link" in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, symlink

I'm now running an Android App project on Windows and running into the condition

> Error:Could not list contents of
>   'D:\source\App\src\main\res\drawable'. Couldn't follow symbolic link.

after did the clean build.

Android Studio states the drawable file is a broken symbolic link.

I just check other related post online but still cannot figure out what does that mean, why is that happened, and how to fix it. Can anyone help to give me a clue to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still do not know the real reason but problem solved by re-checkout source.
Clean build did not work so I guess there's just something wrong in the project build-up steps.

Answer (score 23):

Next time to save time you can run the following command:

```
find . -type l -exec test ! -e {} \; -delete
```

Comment: Does this delete all broken symbolic links?

Comment: and run this in your app base, not android folder :D

Comment: I don't know what I could do without this. Thanks... I believe this should be marked as answer

Answer (score 1):

I have always resolved this issue by using
unlink followed by the path where it's not finding symbolic link.

example: unlink ./bin/uuid

Answer (score 1):

Removing .bin did not work, but `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` did the trick.

Comment: Please be careful with posting extremely similar answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46270286/build-failed-generated-build-apk-react-native/65197187#65197187 Consider flagging as duplicate....

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to node modules folder of particular package, and delete the .bin folder

Eg:

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.

  > Could not list contents of '/home/centillion/Documents/CMC/cmc-mobile-repo/node_modules/react-native-image-slider/node_modules/.bin/flow'. **Couldn't follow symbolic link**.

For this case, navigate to node modules/react-native-image-slider/node modules and delete .bin folder and rerun. 
NOTE: To view hidden folders, press `CTRL + H`