# Build Failed Generated Build APK react native

Tags: android, react-native

I Want generated build apk but after cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease build failed.

there my info:

```
* What went wrong:
  Could not list contents of '/Users/sweet/Desktop/phase/ka-
  mobile/node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4/test-driver'. 
  Couldn't follow symbolic link.
```

i already put ***my-release-key.keystore*** under android/app
and change ***android/app/build.gradle***

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.kickavenue"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
signingConfigs {
    release {
        if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
}
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

and change ***android/gradle.properties*** or change on ***~/.gradle/gradle.properties***

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true   //only on android/gradle.properties i write
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-release-key.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=sample
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=sample
```

there is wrong my step to build genereated APK

Answer (score 0):

What version of RN are you using? This issue appears on RN 0.46.3 as stated on React Native's github: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14464

You could upgrade to React Native 0.47.0 to fix the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try deleting the `.bin` folder inside your `node_modules`